# print a same line several times in perl

Tags: perl

I want to output in one line which is fine now, like:

```
print "$a\t" x 99;
print "$b\n";
```

So above is how one line looks like. But I also want to print these lines `$c` times. Is there a shortcut to do that rather than using for loops like:

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= $c; $i++) {
  print "$a\t" x 99;
  print "$b\n";
}
```

Is there simpler ways to do so, just like `"$a\t" x 99`?

Comment: Please note that [`$a`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#%24a) and [`$b`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#%24b) are poor choices for variable names in perl, even in throw-away examples, because of their [specialness](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#%24a).

Comment: The *C-style* for loop is almost never useful in Perl. Use `for (LIST) { .. }` instead.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
for (1 .. $how_many) { print "$foo\t" x 99, "$bar\n"; }
```

is IMO simpler than C-style for (;;) loops.

Comment: In fact, this is preferable to `((("$a\t" x 99)."$b\n") x $c)` because it doesn't increase memory usage by creating a potentially large list to pass to `print`.

Comment: If we're talking optimization, a `while` loop will also avoid creating a list of numbers for the loop. E.g. `print ... while $i++ <= $how_many`

Comment: @TLP: you're very out of date! `perlop` (Range Operators) says, *In the current implementation, no temporary array is created when the range operator is used as the expression in foreach loops*.

Comment: @TLP: Nice.  Also, `print ... while $how_many--`, assuming we're not too naively trusting of `$how_many`.

Comment: @Borodin That's good news, and an interesting fact. Such a comment deserves upvoting, but unfortunately I cannot, since you called me and not my information "out of date", so I will leave that to others.

Comment: @pilcrow A little more dangerous, but it works. I would prefer my own version, though, since it is safer.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, and you've already got all you need for it.

```
print ((("$a\t" x 99)."$b\n") x $c);
```